# Data integration tool that supports Semantic Web

Tags: tool-request, rdf

I've multiple data sources (files or API data). I want to integrate all these sources using one common ontology.

I've started using [Karma Information Integration Tool](https://github.com/usc-isi-i2/Web-Karma); however, I'm facing some execution errors with its service.

I'm looking for alternative solution. I wonder if [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) still supporting RDF and ontologies ?

**Edit**

It's very important for us to have a defined mapping between ontology and data source (e.g., a web service). This allows us to apply automatically mapping every time we get new data from the source.

Comment: Well, GraphDB OntoRefine supports CSV, JSON, XML etc. sources. Documentation says that support for other formats can be added with OpenRefine extensions. RML supports many types of sources: http://rml.io/RMLdataRetrieval.html. There also exists SPARQL-Generate: https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/sparql-generate/

Comment: For OntoRefine/OpenRefine I see that data integration have to be done inside the application. We cannot define mapping once, then we use it to annotate new data from same data source.
In contrast, SPARQL Generate and RML are promising. Unfortunately, I cannot find how to install their editor. 
I opt for  SPARQL Generate since it more natural because it uses SPARQL. In addition, it's in continuous development.
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: OK. It seems that RML Editor is not available now, one should use RML Mapper directly. RML extends W3C-standardized R2RML. An example on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49380987/7879193

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at https://data.world for the data aggregation right now (disclaimer, I work there...but it's a free resource). You can aggregate multiple data sources quite easily. Our entire site is also built on top of semantic web and linked data tech. In the very near future we'll be rolling out tools for you to link your data semantically, as well as features to help with the ontological features that you're requesting.

So, while it's not 100% of what you're asking for, it should be >100% of what you're looking for very soon (weeks, not months or years). In the meantime it should handle the aggregation piece quite nicely. If you have any questions feel free to ask me @scuttlemonkey at https://slack.data.world or https://forum.data.world.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I really like what data.world is doing, but it seems that registration is always required, which may turn away some people to hosting their data there.